# Logarithm of a matrix

Tags: lie-algebras, linear-algebra

I am looking for a reference to study logarithm of an invertible triangular matrix. What is a good algorithm? Are there any good reference which studies this topic both theoretically and from an algorithm view point? I am also looking for structure of the logarithm of an upper/lower triangular invertible matrix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [*"Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation"*](http://books.google.com/books?id=S6gpNn1JmbgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=functions+of+matrices&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=2ePrTfX3E8bFswa6_d3nCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Higham. Chapter 11 is specifically devoted to the matrix logarithm. In  particular, the chapter contains a thorough comparison of four different numerical algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

If your matrix is triangular, you can read off the eigenvalues, and it is not hard to find the eigenvector/generalized eigenvectors. Once you have those, it is easy to find the logarithm.

Comment: WHat is the algorithm though? Is there a particular structure for log of upper traingular matrix? By that I mean: if $U$ is upper triangular, is there any structure to $exp(U)$. thank you.

Comment: I mean $log(U)$

Comment: $\log(U)$ is upper triangular.

Comment: @Federico Poloni That is correct it is upper triangular since all powers of U are upper triangular. Thankyou.